# Can We connect handycam to Opencv

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

Everyone knows to connect webcam in opencv we can connect as `cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)` But can we connect Sony Handycam in the same way or we need to do something else i am new in cv2 searched a lot on how to connect Handycam in cv2 but did not found if anyone tried or have idea (reference) can you tell me how can I do that

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31478137/capturing-video-from-android-smartphone-using-opencv-python

Comment: https://www.quora.com/How-can-I-connect-my-phone-camera-or-USB-camera-in-OpenCV-Python

Comment: https://github.com/CptFoobar/AndroidCamFeed

Comment: https://www.hackster.io/peter-lunk/how-to-use-the-android-ip-webcam-app-with-python-opencv-45f28f

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Capturing Video from Android Smartphone using OpenCV Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31478137/capturing-video-from-android-smartphone-using-opencv-python)

Answer (score 1):

Connect the handycam to the computer via USB and install all necessary drivers. Then you can use any normal code with cv2 for handycam access, except you might have to change the device ID.

```
import cv2

cam_ID=0 ## Change the 0 value to whatever ID your device has.(0 is first camera, 1 is second camera and so on...)
cam = cv2.VideoCapture(cam_ID) 
while True:
    value, img = cam.read()
    cv2.imshow('my webcam', img)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) == 27: 
        break  # esc to quit
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: How do you know what the cam_ID is?

Comment: It depends on the number of cameras you have attached... You can find it simply by trial-and-error.

Comment: Its a Handycam not webcam how can we connect Handycam