# Stream live video on Android Phone

Tags: python, android, udp

So I wanted to stream my laptop webcam video on my phone using UDP Socket connection. I have written the code for client and server in python first but it has come to my understanding that cv.videocapture which I have used in python can not be used in Android.
How can I capture the video sent by the server(my laptop).

**Server Code**

```
import socket
import numpy
import time
import cv2

UDP_IP=" 192.168.115.129"
UDP_PORT = 5000
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
sock.bind((UDP_IP, UDP_PORT))

s=""

while True:
    print("Hello")
    data, addr = sock.recvfrom(46080)
    print("Hello1")
    s+= data
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
```

**Client Code** (In Python, how can I change this to use in Android since I can not use videocapture)

```
import socket
import numpy as np
import cv2
UDP_IP = ' 192.168.115.129'                  
UDP_PORT = 5000

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
while(True):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    cv2.imshow('Testing',frame)
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    d = frame.flatten ()
    s = d.tostring ()
    for i in xrange(20):
        sock.sendto (s[i*46080:(i+1)*46080],(UDP_IP, UDP_PORT))


        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Its easier to process video in python first and then send it to android

Comment: check here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31478137/capturing-video-from-android-smartphone-using-opencv-python

Comment: Most of them are using http. I have already implemented http connection but I get a lot of frame drops. So I'm trying UDP now.